# mouseover fired with mouse still and element moving

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, onmouseover

I am in a situation where I need jQuery's `mouseover` event to be fired when an element (in this case an image) moves under the mouse, so unlike the common situation is an element that is moving, not the mouse.

Do you know of any library/gist/technology that could help me in this sense?

I've tried with flash but with no luck, is this something than can actually be done?

Comment: what makes the element (in your case an image) moving?

Comment: @Anwar Chandra: I move it with jQuery's `css`, assigning to it a certain `left` and `top`, recalling the "moving function" in a timeout. Right now I'm looking at html5 canvas to see if it provides something that could help me.

Comment: as fas as i know, there is no such event even in HTML5. my friend created a game (with HTML5) in chrome web store that need this kind of event but can't find solution until now.

Answer (score 2):

You can track mouse position by binding a handler to [mousemove](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/) on the body, and calculate after every move of the image whether the pointer is over it.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to avoid any kind of calculation, trying to leverage browser events... but it seems it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across a similar issue. In my case I did a "good enough" workaround by keeping track of the time the mouse last moved and then in the mouseover handler seeing if the mouse had moved recently -- within 30ms of the current time. That way I can bail out in cases where the mouse didn't actually move, but I don't have to test the hitboxes myself -- something very hard to do right and fast, and fortunately something I can leave to the browser by doing this.

Comment: Also see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761730/webkit-firing-mousemove-event-unexpectedly-mouse-not-moving