# Webkit firing mousemove event unexpectedly (mouse not moving)

Tags: javascript, webkit, dom-events, interactive, scrollto

I have a slideshow playing that scrolls a div to reveal the next photo in the slideshow. I also have a function set up that hides the photo description when the mouse is inactive, but shows the description when the mouse moves.

In Firefox, there is no problem, the div scrolls to new photos and no `mousemove` event is fired. However, in Webkit with the mouse on the window, but inactive, two-three `mousemove` events are fired every time the div scrolls to a new photo.

Here's the website for you to have a look. Navigate to the portfolio page in a webkit browser (with a console open I suppose) and that footer should stay hidden while the photos cycle through. http://96.0.13.132/

Comment: For future reference, you should post the website first so your question doesn't get votes to close in the mean time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, webkit browsers do that, and i think every browser should. Because the cursor **IS** in a different position after the scrolling, and that could avoid me a lot of problems as a developer.

Anyway, if you want to avoid its consequences in your script, just log the latest clientX and clientY position and check if those have changed since the last "mousemove"; something like this:

```
window.addEventListener("mousemove",function(e){
    if(window.lastX !== e.clientX || window.lastY !== e.clientY){
        // Code when the (physical) mouse actually moves
    }   
    window.lastX = e.clientX
    window.lastY = e.clientY
})
```